# using grunt plugins in a grunt plugin

Tags: gruntjs

I'm writing a (my first) grunt plugin but I cannot figure out how to import other plugins to use them in my plugin.
I've npm install the required plugins (both globally and locally to the project folder) but I keep getting a cannot find module grunt-env and grunt-msbuild.
Any Idea on how to fix that?

here is my code:

```
'use strict';

 module.exports = function (grunt) {
     var 
        env = require('grunt-env'),
        msbuild = require('grunt-msbuild');
};
```

Comment: can you run `npm list --depth=0` on your project folder, this will list the installed modules in your local folder. `npm list -g --depth=0` will list global modules.

Comment: the plugins are listed with npm list --depth=0
    ├── grunt-env@0.4.1
    ├── grunt-msbuild@0.2.2

Comment: I have no idea, try posting the error here, and try using node repl, and manually do a `require('grunt-env')`.